# Who was the body in the lake?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-sinner

In the twisty Netflix psychological drama [The Sinner (season 2)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6048596/episodes?season=2&ref_=tt_eps_sn_2) a great deal of the plot revolves around Marin, a troubled teen who joins a cult but later disappears years before the action we see.

At one point it is suspected she is dead and the police, acting on a tipoff, search a lake and find a body in a car. We assume at the time that the body is Marin.

It later turns out that it is not Marin as she is still alive.

Who is it and what is their relationship to the cult?

Answer (score 1):

It was a [suicide victim](https://www.vulture.com/2018/09/the-sinner-recap-season-2-episode-7-part-vii.html) - Britt Jacob: a Deakins resident with no relation to the Mosswood cult. She suffered from clinical depression, hence the suicide is the most likely COD.

But the fact that one cult member mentioned that there might be bodies in the lake and that someone tipped off the police about the location of a suicide victim  makes this situation bit dodgy. Especially if you add to it the fact, that the body was found in the car in the lake, so it couldn't be accidentally spotted and (to my best knowledge) driving to the lake is not the most popular way of committing suicide.

But besides that, the whole plot is a giant red herring.